# Windows Phone Navigation transitions blank screen in between transitions

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm using WP Toolkit to do the transitions between my app pages, it works fine , but I get this strange delay in between transitions while navigating from one page to another, it just shows a blank(black) screen which obviously doesn't look good. I also Need How to implement this in my app. I'd appreciate it if someone can help me with it or suggest another page transition library.

Comment: Can you please provide some code and/or xaml

Comment: Dont copy the entire question from another link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15696075/windows-phone-navigation-transitions-delay-and-blank-screen-in-between